A bounded sequence but does not converge
Let $A = \{ (x_{n})_{n} \subset \mathbb{R} \mid (x_{n})_{n}  \text{ has finitely many non-zero elements} \}$.
Prove that $A$ is not a $Banach$ space in $l^\infty$.
And I've been struggled to find a sequence that bounded but does not converge. I think that
$$
(a_n) = \bigl\{1, \tfrac{1}{2}, \dots ,\tfrac{1}{n}, 0, 0, \dots \bigr\}
$$
works, but I can't prove that it does not converge.
Could you guys help me prove that $a_n$ does not converge or suggest me an easier sequence?

Your example seems correct to me. To prove that it doesn't converge to anything in $A$, you could start by assuming that there is a limit $(x_n) \in A$. Can you find $\epsilon > 0$ so that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $m \geq n$ so $| (a_k)m- (x_n)|\infty > \epsilon$?

If $a_n\to a$ in $A$ then (by continuity of the canonical projections $l^\infty\to\Bbb R$) $$\forall k\in\Bbb N\quad a(k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(k)=\frac1k\ne0,$$ hence $a\notin A$: contradiction.
